# Akka.NET: Dead Letters to Remote Actor

Tags: f#, akka.net, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am learning how to call a remote actor from a different machine. To simulate two different machines I have a Host machine and the other one is a Virtual Machine (VM). The Network Adapter is set to `NAT` because with this setting I am able to ping the host machine from VM (I read that it should be set to Bridge but the ping command timed out).

```
Host IP: 172.16.104.242
VM IP: 10.0.2.15
```

That aside, this is the code for `RemoteActor.fsx` on host machine

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"

open System
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.FSharp

let config =
    Configuration.parse
        @"akka {
            actor.provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
            remote.helios.tcp {
                hostname = 172.16.104.242
                port = 9001
            }
        }"

let system = System.create "RemoteFSharp" config
let echoServer = 
    spawn system "EchoServer"
    <| fun mailbox ->
        let rec loop() =
            actor {
                let! message = mailbox.Receive()
                let sender = mailbox.Sender()
                printfn "echoServer called"
                match box message with
                | :? string -> 
                    sender <! sprintf "Echo: %s" message
                    return! loop()
                | _ ->  failwith "Unknown message"
            }
        loop()
```

I first executed this script and this is the output
[image]

This is the code for `LocalActor.fsx` on VM

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"

open System
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.FSharp

let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                deployment {
                    /remoteecho {
                        remote = ""akka.tcp://RemoteFSharp@172.16.104.242:9001""
                    }
                }
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 0
                    hostname = 10.0.2.15
                }
            }
        }")

let system = ActorSystem.Create("RemoteFSharp", configuration)
let echoClient = system.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteFSharp@172.16.104.242:9001/EchoServer")
let task = echoClient <? "F#!"
let response = Async.RunSynchronously (task, 1000)
printfn "Reply from remote %s" (string(response))
```

This is the output for this
[image: Local Remote]

Now the `RemoteActor.fsx` throws this error
[image: Error]

I found a few posts on Stack Overflow that had this same error but couldn't figure out the fix. Apparently the error is because the `RemoteActor` dies before the `Local Actor` sends the message. Also after running the `RemoteActor.fsx` script if I type this `echoServer <! "Hello"` in the `RemoteActor` terminal, I get the same error.

Any idea how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
let echoClient = system.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteFSharp@172.16.104.242:9001/EchoServer")
```

To

```
let echoClient = system.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteFSharp@172.16.104.242:9001/user/EchoServer")
```

All user-defined actors exist under the `/user` actor root.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! "These violent bugs have violent consequences”